# Recurrence formula in generating functions

Tags: generating-functions

I wanted to know that is there a way to find generating function for a sequence without finding a recurrence formula for it ?
If there isn't;
Is there a formula for finding recurrence formula it-self?

Comment: What do you know about the sequence?

Comment: It's just add up like +6 +3 +2 and just that for first 4 numbers in sequence

Comment: Sequence is 1,7,10,12,...

Comment: https://oeis.org/A184114

Comment: What if I want to find it myself?

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to generate a sequence with those four terms.  Which way do you have in mind?

Comment: Ok then. You mean that there's not ONE way. Thank you for your time !(I have my answer)

Comment: Using only the information in your question? I think you can answer that yourself.